# How to get the regular expression checked word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the regular expression checked word without using any loop.
We can replace the #, when the word is occur by like below

```
(str).replace(/\w+/g,"#")

("words1 words2").replace(\/w+,"#")   => # #
```

But I want to get the "words1 and words2 instead of #"

I tried like below

```
$("#in_text").val()).replace(/\w+/g,this.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+this.substring(1,(this.length-1));
```

How can I access the checked word instead of **this** key word.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions Check this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass function to [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function:

```
var newValue = $("#in_text").val().replace(/\w+/g,function(match){  
     return match.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+match.substring(1,(match.length-1));
});
```